# Setting secrets as environment variables in deployment file

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-secrets

I'm currently working on a Kubernetes deployment file and I need to set the environment variables that the container will have.

Is there a way to set Kubernetes secrets as environment variables in the deployment file?

Here is a dummy file to help explain:

[image: dummy deployment file]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, of course, you can mount env variables from config maps or secrets with

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata: ...
spec:
  ...
  template:
    ...
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: app
          image: ...
          envFrom:
          - configMapRef:
              name: env-configmap
          - secretRef:
              name: env-secrets
```

See more in the official doc: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/#using-secrets-as-environment-variables

Answer (score 1):

The syntax that worked for me was:

```
spec:
  ...
  template:
    ...
    spec
      ...
      containers:
          env:
            - name: PORT
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: env-configmap
                  key: PORT
            - name: ELASTIC_PASSWORD
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: env-secret
                  key: ELASTIC_PASSWORD
```

The other syntax may also work and be acceptable, I'm just offering this answer as another alternative syntax for *mapping* Kubernetes configuration and secret values into environment variables.

When I checked the [URL referenced in the answer from @Valentin BOUSSON](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/#using-secrets-as-environment-variables).
The page now (2023-05-16) says:

> To use a Secret in an environment variable in a Pod:
>
> For each container in your Pod specification, add an environment variable for each Secret key that you want to use to the env[].valueFrom.secretKeyRef field.
> Modify your image and/or command line so that the program looks for values in the specified environment variables.

Comment: also use base64 encoding for sensitive data in your ConfigMap file